# Android requestPinAppWidget returns false after recent installation

Tags: android, android-widget, samsung-mobile, android-8.0-oreo

I'm having issues with `AppWidgetManager::requestPinAppWidget`

Sometimes the method `requestPinAppWidget` returns false. We reproduce it by uninstalling the app and installing again from fresh using android studio. We can consistently reproduce it on Samsung and Pixel devices using this code:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun showWidgetAddingActivity(context: Context) {
    val appWidgetManager = context.applicationContext.getSystemService(AppWidgetManager::class.java)
    val myProvider = ComponentName(context.applicationContext, WidgetActionsReceiver::class.java)

    val launcherSupported = appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider,null, null)
}
```

the value of `launcherSupported` will be `false` if we run this after a fresh installation (or within a few minutes afterward). And it will be `true` in any other case

Calling appWidgetManager.isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported always returns true when this happens.

Why is that? How can I mitigate it? Or at least know about it in advance so I won't show the user the rest of the flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by `WidgetActionsReceiver` being disabled by default. When it was enabled using a feature flag, it took time for the change to reach the launcher.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by `WidgetActionsReceiver` being disabled and how you enabled it?

Comment: I don't remember at this point, I believe that this was disabled in AndroidManifest? 3 years later and no longer have access to the codebase :(